# Understanding Applicative Evaluation Order with the Z-Combinator

Tags: computability, lambda-calculus, computation-models, python, evaluation-strategies

I am trying to understand how the Z-combinator (Y-combinator for applicative order languages) definition came about. As Python is applicative I am using Python for this.

So I know Python's evaluation order is applicative. But I seem to be overlooking something in how applicative order works. To compensate for applicative evaluation order I reasoned to build a Y-combinator that does not dive off into infinite recursion it would be sufficient to write it like this:

```
Y = lambda f : (lambda x : f( lambda z: x(x) (z) )) (lambda x : f(x(x)))
```

I arrived at this conclusion by first manually deriving `Y g` like so

```
Y g =  (lambda f : (lambda x : f(x x)) (lambda x : f(x x))) g      # Definition of Y
    -> (lambda x : g(x x)) (lambda x : g(x x))                   # beta reduction
    -> g((lambda x : g(x x)) (lambda x : g(x x)))                # beta reduction
    -> g((lambda f : (lambda x : f(x x)) (lambda x : f(x x))) g) # lambda abstraction
    =  g(Y g)                                                    # put in Y
```

And then working my way backwards like this, adding in a lambda abstraction hat would delay the recursion until a value is passed in:

```
    = g(lambda z : Y g z)                                                   
    =  g(lambda z : (lambda f (lambda x : f(x x)) (lambda x : f(x x))) g z) 
    -> g(lambda z : (lambda x : g(x x)) (lambda x : g(x x)) z)         
    -> (lambda x : g(lambda z : x x z)) (lambda x : g(x x))            
Y g =  (lambda f : (lambda x : f( lambda z : x x z)) (lambda x : f(x x))) g
```

When I manually evaluate `factorial 3` where

```
factorial_ = lambda f : lambda n : 1 if n == 0 else n * f(n-1)

factorial = Y(factorial_)
```

in applicative order I get

```
 factorial 3 =  (lambda n : 1 if n == 0 else n * (lambda z : Y factorial_ z)(n-1)) 3       
            -> 3 * (lambda z : Y factorial_ z)(3-1)                                  
            -> 3 * (Y factorial_ 2)                                             
            =  3 * ((lambda n : 1 if n == 0 else n * (lambda z : Y factorial_ z)(n-1)) 2)
            -> 3 * 2 * ((lambda z : Y factorial_ z)(2-1))
            -> 3 * 2 * (Y factorial_ 1)
            =  3 * 2 * ((lambda n : 1 if n == 0 else n * (lambda z : Y factorial_ z)(n-1)) 1)
            -> 3 * 2 * 1 * ((lambda z : Y factorial_ z)(1-1))
            -> 3 * 2 * 1 * (Y factorial_ 0)
            =  3 * 2 * 1 * ((lambda n : 1 if n == 0 else n * (lambda z : Y factorial_ z)(n-1)) 0)
            -> 3 * 2 * 1 * 1
            -> 6
```

But when I run

```
Y = lambda f : (lambda x : f( lambda z: x(x) (z) )) (lambda x : f(x(x)))

factorial_ = lambda f : lambda n : 1 if n == 0 else n * f(n-1)

factorial = Y(factorial_)

print(factorial(3))
```

I still get the infinite recursion problem:

> Y = lambda f : (lambda x : f( lambda z: x(x) (z) )) (lambda x :
>   f(x(x)))   [Previous line repeated 994 more times] RecursionError:
>   maximum recursion depth exceeded

So I must not actually have performed correct applicative order on my manual derivation, otherwise I would have gotten infinite recursion like Python gets.

What am I missing here about how applicative order works?

## EDIT:

To reiterate:

Let's say I name that version of `Y` `Z'`:

Let $Z' = \lambda f. \lambda x( f ( \lambda z. x x z)) (\lambda x. f( xx))$

Let $F' = \lambda f. \lambda n. 1 \text{ if } n = 0 \text{ else } n*f(n-1)$
$$ \text{Let } F = Z' F' = (\lambda f . (\lambda x . f( \lambda z . x x z) (\lambda x . f(x x)) F'$$
$$\longrightarrow (\lambda x . F'(\lambda z . x x z)) (\lambda x . F'(x x))$$
$$\longrightarrow F'(\lambda z . (\lambda x . F'(x x)) (\lambda x . F'(x x)) z)$$
Lambda-Abstraction for $F'$
$$=  F'(\lambda z . (\lambda f (\lambda x . f(x x)) (\lambda x . f(x x))) F' z)$$
Per definition of $Z'$
$$= F'(\lambda z . Z' F' z)$$

Now applying $F$ to some number:

$$F~ 3 =  (\lambda n . 1 \text{ if } n = 0 \text{ else } n * (\lambda z . Z' F' z)(n-1)) 3$$

$$\longrightarrow 3 * (\lambda z . Z' F' z)(3-1)                                  $$

$$\longrightarrow 3 * (Z' F' 2)                                             $$
                                         $$=  3 * ((\lambda n . 1 \text{ if } n = 0 \text{ else } n * (\lambda z . Z' F' z)(n-1)) 2) $$
                                         $$\longrightarrow 3 * 2 * ((\lambda z . Z' F' z)(2-1))$$
                                         $$\longrightarrow 3 * 2 * (Z' F' 1)$$
                                         $$=  3 * 2 * ((\lambda n . 1 \text{ if } n = 0 \text{ else } n * (\lambda z . Z' F' z)(n-1)) 1)$$
                                         $$\longrightarrow 3 * 2 * 1 * ((\lambda z . Z' F' z)(1-1))$$
                                         $$\longrightarrow 3 * 2 * 1 * (Z' F' 0)$$
                                         $$=  3 * 2 * 1 * ((\lambda n . 1 \text{ if } n = 0 \text{ else } n * (\lambda z . Z' F' z)(n-1)) 0)$$
                                         $$\longrightarrow 3 * 2 * 1 * 1$$
                                         $$\longrightarrow 6$$

So, why did this work? It was supposed to go into infinite recursion. What is my mistake?

Comment: Your "Per definition of Z′" step is wrong: that would result in $F′(\lambda z.Y F′ z)$ since you lack a $\lambda z$ to use $Z'$ instead (you'd need another $\lambda z$ in the first $\lambda x.f(xx)$ part, which should be $\lambda x.f(\lambda z. xxz)$). And indeed that's the point! Your $Z'$ "recurses" into $Y$ instead of $Z'$ itself.

Comment: Ouh! Yes now I see it. What a silly mistake. Thanks!

Comment: I think it helps noting that both $Y$ and $Z$ manage to achieve recursion using a self-application of the form $MM$ where the first $M$ takes the second one as argument (say $x$), and computes $xx$ which is $MM$ again, hence recursing. If you use $MN$ instead, you end up with $NN$ so you do not start again from the beginning, but from something else. In your case, it happened that $NN$ was, essentially, $Yf$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call your proposal `X`, instead:

```
X = lambda f : (lambda x : f( lambda z: x(x) (z) )) (lambda x : f(x(x)))
```

For convenience, we can rewrite it as

```
M = (lambda x : f(x(x)))    # depends on f
X = lambda f : (lambda x : f( lambda z: x(x) (z) )) M
```

Now, when we invoke `X(f)`, we get

```
X(f) =
(lambda x : f( lambda z: x(x) (z) )) M =
f( lambda z: M(M) (z) )
```

Assume `f` "recurses", invoking its argument with some value, e.g. `5`. Its code might look as

```
c = M(M)(5)
do something with c
return something
```

However, `M(M)` above is exactly the non terminating `Y(f)`. The additional `lambda z:` disappears after the first recursive call.

In order to prevent that, we need to add `lambda z:` inside `M` as well. Hence we get the actual `Z` combinator:

```
Z = lambda f : (lambda x : f( lambda z: x(x) (z) )) (lambda x : f(lambda z: x(x) (z)))
```

Comment: But when we split `Y` into `X` and `M` the `f` in `M` won't be the same as the `f` in `X`, will it? The free `f` in `M` will be alpha-converted so as to not conflict with the bound `f` in `X`, will it not?

Comment: Why do you write `Y(f) = (lambda x : f( lambda z: x(x) (z) )) M`? I thought you wanted to use `X` instead of `Y`. And even `X f` would not be `(lambda x : f( lambda z: x(x) (z) )) M`. Sorry, that part confuses me. Can you add some more explanation to it?

Comment: "However, M(M) above is exactly the non terminating Y(f). The additional lambda z: disappears after the first recursive call."

I am aware that that is what needs to happen. But I don't see where I made a mistake in my derivation.

Comment: I edited my question to with some easier to read math.

Comment: @lotolmencre Actually, it won't be alpha-converted. But anyway, `M` is not important here: just pretend that the `f` in `M` is that one bound in the definition of `X`. (You are right in that I should have used `X(f)`! Hopefully I fixed that now)

Comment: @lotolmencre No, `lambda z:` must not completely disappear after the first iteration, otherwise after the first iteration we continue using `Y` which does not terminate. We must always make it so that, when we evaluate, we never have `f(M(M))` but only `f(lambda z:M(M)(z))` -- the former would evaluate `M(M)` before the call, the latter after the call (and only if needed).